# How to record audio stream from internet radio resourse?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, stream, recording

In my application I play internet audio/radio stream with AVPlayer. I want to save and playing audio. Could you give me a right way to resolve this problem (with example, please).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the link http://blog.evandavey.com/2010/04/how-to-iphone-sdk-play-and-record-audio-concurrently.html hope it will help .

Comment: Thank's for your attention. But I need recording without microphone, only from stream.

Comment: now check this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html and check the question How do I record and play back audio at the same time? and they also stated the sample code for this hope this will helps you

Comment: This thing needing for microphone too. Do you know another way? Do you know a way to locked other noises?

Comment: Sorry Viktor i don't no the other way but by changing codec of a audio file you can reduce/max. a sound file's property on different aspect and for doing so you need to know codec writing in c++ i think you should search any library either in c or in c++ may be you can get some idea from there.If you check the Apple's code on low level they write all things in c an c++ for audio projects .